How to emit from a templated SocketIO websocket class
Hell there, I've been working with SocketIO, and I am trying to create a custom abstract class to create several WebSocket servers that I can type as I want using TypeScript string typing capacity.
I am having errors on the emit function, since everything is templated, I may not be passing the types correctly, which result in compilation errors.
Here was my first take on the problem :
# Taken from Socket.IO source code directly, and omitting symbol type
type EventNames<T> = keyof T & (string)

export abstract class AbstractCustomServer<
  T extends EventsMap = DefaultEventsMap,
  V extends EventsMap = DefaultEventsMap,
  K extends EventsMap = DefaultEventsMap,
  U = any,
> {

  private _server: http.Server
  private _io: socket.Server<T, V, K, U>
  constructor(server: http.Server, opts?: Partial<socket.ServerOptions>) {
    this._server = server
    this._io = new socket.Server<T, V, K, U>(this._server, opts)
  }
  public broadcastData(event: EventNames<V>, ...args: Parameters<V[EventNames<V>]>) {
    const dataToEmit = args.length === 1 ? args[0] : args
    this._io.emit(event, args)
                //^^^^ ERROR
 }
}

That led to the error Type 'EventNames<V>' is not assignable to type 'IfAny<V[EventNames<V>] | Last<Parameters<V[EventNames<V>]>>, EventNames<V>, (keyof V & string extends (Parameters<...> extends never[] ? keyof V & string : never) ? (Parameters<...> extends never[] ? keyof V & string : never) & ... 1 more ... & string : keyof V & string extends (Last<...> extends (...args: any[]) =>...' (Yes, a long one)
I also tried to use Socket.IO types directly in this way:
  public broadcastData(event: EventNames<RemoveAcknowledgements<V>>, args: Parameters<RemoveAcknowledgements<V[EventNames<RemoveAcknowledgements<V>>]>>) {
    const dataToEmit = args.length === 1 ? args[0] : args
    this._io.emit(event, args)
                      //^^^^ ERROR
  }

First, I am getting this error [Parameters<RemoveAcknowledgements<V[EventNames<RemoveAcknowledgements<V>>]>>] not assignable to Parameters<RemoveAcknowledgements<V[EventNames<RemoveAcknowledgements<V>>]>> which I understand, but can't understand why my parameter args turns into an array for some reason.
And secondly, I assume that Socket.IO shouldn't be used this way, such strongly typed parameters "should" be handled in their library, which, by the look of it in their code, is the case.
I also tried this system outside of a class, and it works well until I template the function, then Socket.IO is sending me errors, asking for such specific typings.
Anyone would have any takes on this ?
